# How can I update a Jtextarea once? (mysql side-?)

Tags: java, mysql, database, jtextarea

Ok what I've been trying to do is figure out how to make it so when I press the search button on my program the code that is currently just being printed to the console will print to the text area I have. I can't figure out how to do this and I've searched google and still found no answer.

And while I'm at it if anyone could help me figure out how to send this same line of information to a mysql database that would help greatly.

```
package GTE;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.*;
import twitter4j.*;

public class GTE {

private JFrame frmGte;
public String hashq = "...";
public String twtresults;
public int refresh = 1;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {
                GTE window = new GTE();
                window.frmGte.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Create the application.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FontFormatException 
 */
public GTE(){
    try {
        initialize();
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {} 
    catch (IOException e) {}
}

/**
 * Initialize the contents of the frame.
 * @throws IOException 
 * @throws FontFormatException 
 */
private void initialize() throws FontFormatException, IOException {
    frmGte = new JFrame();
    frmGte.setResizable(false);
    frmGte.setTitle("GTE");
    frmGte.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 390);
    frmGte.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    GridBagLayout gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
    gridBagLayout.columnWidths = new int[]{434, 0};
    gridBagLayout.rowHeights = new int[]{21, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    gridBagLayout.columnWeights = new double[]{0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    gridBagLayout.rowWeights = new double[]{0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, Double.MIN_VALUE};
    frmGte.getContentPane().setLayout(gridBagLayout);

    JLabel GTETitle = new JLabel("Personal Tweet Extractor");
    InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("ultraviolentbb_reg.ttf");
    Font GTEFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT,is);
    Font f = GTEFont.deriveFont(24f);
    GTETitle.setFont(f);
    GTETitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_GTETitle = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_GTETitle.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_GTETitle.anchor = GridBagConstraints.NORTH;
    gbc_GTETitle.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    gbc_GTETitle.gridx = 0;
    gbc_GTETitle.gridy = 0;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(GTETitle, gbc_GTETitle);

    Label label_2 = new Label("~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label_2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label_2.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_label_2.gridx = 0;
    gbc_label_2.gridy = 1;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(label_2, gbc_label_2);

    JLabel SearchTweets = new JLabel("Search For Tweets With" + hashq + ":");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_SearchTweets = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_SearchTweets.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_SearchTweets.gridx = 0;
    gbc_SearchTweets.gridy = 2;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(SearchTweets, gbc_SearchTweets);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("#");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_label.gridx = 0;
    gbc_label.gridy = 3;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(label, gbc_label);

    JButton Search = new JButton("Start Search");
    Search.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            TS(hashq);
            GTE.this.refresh = 0;
            try {
                nulll dialog = new nulll();
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {}
        }

        public void TS(String hashtag){
            Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
            try {
                System.out.println(hashtag);
                QueryResult result = twitter.search(new Query("#" + hashtag));
                List<Tweet> tweets = result.getTweets();
                for (Tweet tweet : tweets) {
                    System.out.println("@" + tweet.getFromUser() + " : " + tweet.getText());
                    GTE.this.twtresults = ("@" + tweet.getFromUser() + " : " + tweet.getText());
                }
            } catch (TwitterException te) {
                te.printStackTrace();
                System.out.println("Failed to search tweets: " + te.getMessage());
                System.exit(-1);
            }
        }

    });

    TextField textField = new TextField();
    textField.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            GTE.this.hashq = evt.getActionCommand();
        }
    });
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textField = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textField.ipadx = 99;
    gbc_textField.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_textField.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textField.gridy = 4;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(textField, gbc_textField);

    GridBagConstraints gbc_Search = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_Search.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_Search.gridx = 0;
    gbc_Search.gridy = 5;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(Search, gbc_Search);

    Label label_1 = new Label("Search Results For Tweets With");
    GridBagConstraints gbc_label_1 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_label_1.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 5, 0);
    gbc_label_1.gridx = 0;
    gbc_label_1.gridy = 6;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(label_1, gbc_label_1);

    TextArea textArea = new TextArea();
    textArea.setText(twtresults);
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    GridBagConstraints gbc_textArea = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc_textArea.gridx = 0;
    gbc_textArea.gridy = 7;
    frmGte.getContentPane().add(textArea, gbc_textArea);


    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    frmGte.setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu Filemenu = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(Filemenu);

    JMenuItem Exititem = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    Exititem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    Filemenu.add(Exititem);

    JMenu Helpmenu = new JMenu("Help");
    menuBar.add(Helpmenu);

    JMenuItem Aboutitem = new JMenuItem("About");
    Helpmenu.add(Aboutitem);
}

}
```

Comment: Please follow the java conventions as stated here: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

It makes your code a lot easier to read!

Comment: Each paragraph of the question should be a separate question.  I believe that the MySQL portion should be removed from this question as it seems to better support the JTextArea update.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I am going to try to answer this the way the code is *written*.

I would think that you would want to update the JTextArea inside the `Search` action listener.  If you moved the `textArea` to be a private attribute of GTE such as:

```
private JFrame frmGte;
private JTextArea textArea;
```

and continue with the rest, then you just simply do:

```
GTE.this.textArea.setText(GTE.this.twtresults)
```

once you have constructed twtresults.  I would imagine you would want the JTextArea updated immediately after you retrieve the tweet.

Now I feel so dirty, I am going to take a bath.